# SQL insert query insert multiple times and don't update

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cordova, insert-update

I want to insert some data that's is send with javascript (cordova app) i send this here

```
var link = 'somelink';
        var stmt = "SELECT * FROM card WHERE Productsync = 0 ";
        //console.log(stmt);
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, stmt).then(function(res) { //console.log(res)
            if(res.rows.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++){
                    console.log(res.rows.item(i));
                    console.log(res.rows.item(i).ProductName);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(i).ProductBarcode);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(i).ProductPakking);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(i).ProductPresent);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(i).ProductMinimuim);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(i).FotoUrl);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(i).DBid);





                    $http.post(link, {ProductName : res.rows.item(i).ProductName , ProductBarcode : res.rows.item(i).ProductBarcode , ProductPakking : res.rows.item(i).ProductPakking , ProductPresent : res.rows.item(i).ProductPresent , ProductMinimuim : res.rows.item(i).ProductMinimuim , FotoUrl : res.rows.item(i).FotoUrl , DBid : res.rows.item(i).DBid}).then(function (res){//sending data
                        console.log(res.data);//respone of server
                        var data = res.data;
                        for (var key in data) {//read out respone
                            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                var obj = data[key];
                                console.log(obj);
                                //have to make this
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }

            }

        });
```

Now i want it to add this in my databases online (BIND variables will i do later) This is how my php script looks like

```
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (isset($postdata)) {
    $request = json_decode($postdata);

    $ProductName = $request->ProductName;
    $ProductBarcode = $request->ProductBarcode;
    $ProductPakking = $request->ProductPakking;
    $ProductPresent = $request->ProductPresent;
    $ProductMinimuim = $request->ProductMinimuim;
    $FotoUrl = $request->FotoUrl;
    $DBid = $request->DBid;



    $ProductName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$ProductName);
    $ProductBarcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$ProductBarcode);
    $ProductPakking = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$ProductPakking);
    $ProductPresent = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$ProductPresent);
    $ProductMinimuim = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$ProductMinimuim);
    $FotoUrl = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$FotoUrl);
    $DBid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$DBid); 
     $query ="REPLACE into `card` (ProductName,ProductBarcode,ProductPakking,ProductPresent,ProductMinimuim,FotoUrl,DBid)
        VALUES( '" . $ProductName . "' ,
                '" . $ProductBarcode . "' ,
                '" . $ProductPakking . "' ,
                '" . $ProductPresent . "' ,
                '" . $ProductMinimuim . "' ,
                '" . $FotoUrl . "' ,
                '" . $DBid ."')";
```

When I echo the $ProductName before the query in php, i just see the productsnames (what I want)

My problem is: it don't replace the value if it already exists, and it insert multiple times, it have to insert just one time and replace or update if the column already exists.

Can someone help my ?

**UPDATE QUERY IN PHP**

```
            $query ="SELECT ProductName FROM `card` WHERE
                `ProductName` = '" . $ProductName . "' AND
                `ProductBarcode` = '" . $ProductBarcode . "' AND
                `ProductPakking` = '" . $ProductPakking . "' AND
                `ProductPresent` = '" . $ProductPresent . "' AND
                `ProductMinimuim` = '" . $ProductMinimuim . "' AND
                `FotoUrl` = '" . $FotoUrl . "' AND
                `DBid` = '" . $DBid ."'";
        $result_set = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_set) == 0){
            $query ="INSERT INTO `card` (ProductName,ProductBarcode,ProductPakking,ProductPresent,ProductMinimuim,FotoUrl,DBid)
            VALUES( '" . $ProductName . "' ,
                    '" . $ProductBarcode . "' ,
                    '" . $ProductPakking . "' ,
                    '" . $ProductPresent . "' ,
                    '" . $ProductMinimuim . "' ,
                    '" . $FotoUrl . "' ,
                    '" . $DBid ."')";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        }else{

            $query = "UPDATE `card`
            SET  `ProductName` = '" . $ProductName . "' ,
                `ProductBarcode` = '" . $ProductBarcode . "' ,
                `ProductPakking` = '" . $ProductPakking . "' ,
                `ProductPresent` = '" . $ProductPresent . "' ,
                `ProductMinimuim` = '" . $ProductMinimuim . "' ,
                `FotoUrl` = '" . $FotoUrl . "' ,
                `DBid` = '" . $DBid ."'
            WHERE `ProductBarcode` = '" . $ProductBarcode . "' AND `DBid` = '" . $DBid ."'";

            $fines = mysqli_query($connection,$query);


        }
```

Comment: If I'm correct, `userID` is the Primary Key of `card` table, and you're not passing `userID` to the `REPLACE` query.

Comment: sorry, my bad, i have'd work on the respone yet, It just about the databases online...

Answer (score 0):

Note that for this approach (or the REPLACE INTO approach or even the ON DUPLICATE KEY approach) to be successfull you need to have a unique index on the fields that you don't want duplicated.

From [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) states

REPLACE makes sense only if a table has a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index. Otherwise, it becomes equivalent to INSERT, because there is no index to be used to determine whether a new row duplicates another.

Comment: so REPLACE is in this case not a option, What's you're advice for this case. I need to insert if not exists and update if exists

Comment: Before do a insert, select the row with all values to be inserted. And if select return row then you'd update it otherwise insert.

Comment: I made a query. But it seems not to work. is the query correct or is there a other problem, update is in the question

Comment: Your update query has error. It should be update `card` SET  `productName` = <value> , `ProductBarcode` = <value> , ... It should not concat with `AND`

Comment: okay I made the fix the error but it still insert multiple times

Comment: Have you tried the select query in our database directly to ensure query return records?

Comment: Don't do really know what you're mean, can you give a example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118657/discussion-between-robin-de-cock-and-tamil).

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have some issue with below lines

```
console.log(res.data);//respone of server
var data = res.data;
for (var key in data) {
```

this loop has some problem because if it json then it iterate over all key one by one and it insert multiple of keys record keys injson * number of time response

please provide res.data logs and also check what you get in key and how many time you looping around that loop.

Comment: ooo yes but that's the respone, I will make this later. my problem now is the the insert. When i work on the respone data, I will think about what you said and find go find a solution